# Как отключить панель в Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Мне нужно заменить стандартную панель в Linux Mint Mate на tint2, но как отключить/убрать из автозагрузки стандартную панель? Я в параметрах запускаемых приложений снял галку с пункта "MATE Panel Compiz"(возможно что это не оно) но стандартная панель все равно запускается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я удалил панель "sudo apt-get remove mate-panel"
Далее я скачал и установил в автозапуск панель 'tint2'.

Comment: Отметь ответ как правильный